# Prisma transaction middleware in NestJs

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, middleware, prisma, nest

Instead of having to declare a new prisma.$transaction to get a prisma instance capable of auto rollbacks for each api request that I need, I'm trying to externalize this responsability to somewhere.

My best try at the moment it's a Transaction Middleware, whic it works, I can declare exactly where I need and recieve the prisma instance on the controller via the request or a param decorator (since I'm using Nest).

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import { PrismaService } from '../prisma.service'

@Injectable()
export class TransacitonMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly prisma: PrismaService) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await this.prisma.$transaction(async (instance) => {
      req['prisma'] = instance

      next() // => GET /user
    })
  }
}
```

```
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Req
} from '@nestjs/common'

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  @Get()
  async findAll(@Req() request: any) {
    const { prisma } = request

    const users = await prisma.user.findMany()

    return users
  }
}
```

However, the prisma requests needs to be made while the prisma.$transaction is still open and, due to the sync behavior of the Express Next Function, the transaction will always close before the end of the request.

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation in .../users.controller.ts:35:37

  32 async findAll(@Req() request: any) {
  33   const { prisma } = request
  34 
→ 35   const users = await prisma.user.findMany(
Transaction API error: Transaction already closed: A query cannot be executed on a committed transaction. at An.handleRequestError...
```

First I've tried to make the nextFunction async somehow, putting an await on it, putting it inside an async function, neither worked.

Then I tried to prolongue the life of the transaction somehow, I declared another prisma request just after the next function inside the middleware and it worked.

```
  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await this.prisma.$transaction(async (instance) => {
      req['prisma'] = instance

      next() // => GET /user

      await instance.user.count()
    })
  }
```

However, due to obvious reasons, I don't think this is a good practice, and I currently exausted my options and time to deliver this. So if someone has any idea on how to make this works, please make an contribution.

Thank you all for the time and consideration!